# SQl query to calculate number of active users at the end of everyday

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, gaps-and-islands

I have three columns `User_ID, New_Status and DATETIME`.

`New_Status` contains 0(inactive) and 1(active) for users. 
Every user starts from active status - ie. 1. 
Subsequently table stores their status and `datetime` at which they got activated/inactivated.

How to calculate number of active users at the end of each date, including dates when no records were generated into the table.

Sample data:

```
| ID | New_Status |      DATETIME       |
+----+------------+---------------------+
| 1  |      1     | 2019-01-01 21:00:00 |
| 1  |      0     | 2019-02-05 17:00:00 |
| 1  |      1     | 2019-03-06 18:00:00 |
| 2  |      1     | 2019-01-02 01:00:00 |
| 2  |      0     | 2019-02-03 13:00:00 |
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: *How to calculate number of active users at the end of each date.* Generate dates list in CTE. Calculate `SUM(CASE WHEN New_Status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY datetime)`.

Comment: Hi @LearningEveryday, I see you are new to Stack Overflow. You have asked here for help and people have helped with their time and expertise. It would be nice to give some answer to this people... They deserve at least your comment as you have done to some answers. They also deserve a vote up if they helped you in any way to learn something or to come to the answer faster... And finaly if you find a correct answer you can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Format the date time value to a date only string and group by it

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATETIME, '%Y-%m-%d') as day, COUNT(*) as active
FROM test
WHERE New_Status = 1
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

Comment: Not all dates are listed in test table even though there will be active users. This won't give me count of active users on all dates.

Comment: This is not ok(my opinion). What if users starts with 1, during the day he goes to 0. Two records, status is inactive and this will show one active...

Comment: @VBoka That kind of requirement wasn't part of the question, how do you know the user is updated several times per day? Besides, that is not the major problem with this answer is it?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you are correct. It is not a part of question. I have to confes I do not understand 100% this : "This won't give me count of active users on all dates." IS this sum of all users for all dates ?

Comment: How ? Here is a demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aaab3a3d4dc7eb6581d23e9140082c9f

Comment: Well, you have my vote up, because this is the only one that works here (and if the opionon from the my first comment is not valid this is also a correct answer.). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8 you can use the `row_number()` window function to get the last status of a user per day. Then filter for the one that indicate the user was active `GROUP BY` the day and count them.

```
SELECT date(x.datetime),
       count(*)
       FROM (SELECT date(t.datetime) datetime,
                    t.new_status,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY date(t.datetime)
                                       ORDER BY t.datetime DESC) rn
                    FROM elbat t) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1
             AND x.new_status = 1
       GROUP BY x.datetime;
```

If not all days are in the table you need to create a (possibly derived) table with all days and cross join it.

Answer (score 1):

## Find out the last activity status of users whose activity was changed for each day

```
select User_ID, New_Status, DATE_FORMAT(DATETIME, '%Y-%m-%d')
from activity_table
where not exists
(
    select 1
    from activity_table at
    where at.User_ID = activity_table.User_ID and
          DATE_FORMAT(at.DATETIME, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(activity_table.DATETIME, '%Y-%m-%d') and
          at.DATETIME > activity_table.DATETIME
)
order by DATE_FORMAT(activity_table.DATETIME, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

This is not the solution yet, but a very very useful information before solution. Note that here not all dates are covered yet and the values are individual records, more precisely their last values on each day, ordered by the date.

## Let's get aggregate numbers

Using the query above as a subselect and aliasing it into a `table`, you can `group by DATETIME` and do a `select sum(new_Status) as activity, count(*) total, DATETIME` so you will know that `activity - (total - activity)` is the difference in comparison to the previous day.

## Knowing the delta for each day present in the result

At the previous section we have seen how the delta can be calculated. If the whole query in the previous section is aliased, then you can self join it using a left join, with pairs of (previous date, current date), still having the gaps of dates, but not worrying about that just yet. In the case of the first date, its `activity` is the delta. For subsequent records, adding the previous day's delta to their delta yields the result you need. To achieve this you can use a recursive query, supported by MySQL 8, or, alternatively, you can just have a subquery which sums the delta of previous days (with special attention to the first date, as described earlier) will and adding the current date's delta yields the result we need.

## Fill the gaps

The previous section would already perfectly work (assuming the lack of integrity problems), assuming that there were activity changes for each day, but we will not continue with the assumption. Here we know that the figures are correct for each date where a figure is present and we will need to just add the missing dates into the result. If the results are properly ordered, as they should be, then one can use a cursor and loop the results. At each record after the first one, we can determine the dates that are missing. There might be 0 such dates between two consequent dates or more. What we do know about the gaps is that their values are exactly the same as the previous record, that do has data. If there were no activity changes on a given date, then the number of active users is exactly the same as in the previous day. Using some structure, like a table you can generate the results you have with the knowledge described here.

## Solving possible integrity problems

There are several possibilities for such problems:

First, a data item might exist prior to the introduction of this table's records were started to be spawned.

Second, bugs or any other causes might have made a pause in creating records for this activity table.

Third, the addition of user is or was not necessarily generating an activity change, since its popping into existence renders its previous state of activity undefined and subject to human standards, which might change over time.

Fourth, the removal of user is or was not necessarily generating an activity change, since its popping out of existence renders is current state of activity undefined and subject to human standards, which might change over time.

Fifth, there is an infinity of other issues which might cause data integrity issues.

To cope with these you will need to comprehensively analyze whatever you can from the source-code and the history of the project, including database records, logs and humanly available information to detect such anomalies, the time they were effective and figure out what their solution is if they exist.

EDIT

In the meantime I was thinking about the possibility of a user, who was active at the start of the day being deactivated and then activated again by the end of the day. Similarly, an inactive user during a day might be activated and then finally deactivated by the end of the day. For users that have more than an activation at the start of the day, we need to compare their activity status at the start and the end of the day to find out what the difference was.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    DATE(DATETIME),
    COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
WHERE New_Status = 1
GROUP BY User_ID,
         DATE(DATETIME)
```

For MySQL

Comment: Not all dates are listed in test table even though there will be active users. This won't give me count of active users on all dates.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte AS (
SELECT MIN(DATE(DT)) dt 
FROM src
UNION ALL
SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
FROM cte 
WHERE dt < ( SELECT MAX(DATE(DT)) dt 
             FROM src )
),
cte2 AS 
(
SELECT users.id, 
       cte.dt, 
       SUM( CASE src.New_Status WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                WHEN 0 THEN -1
                                ELSE 0 
                                END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY users.id
                                             ORDER BY cte.dt ) status
FROM cte
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT id
             FROM src ) users
LEFT JOIN src ON src.id = users.id
             AND DATE(src.dt) = cte.dt
)
SELECT dt, SUM(status)
FROM cte2
GROUP BY dt;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ccd73aa7b2597e08b6f7898a9eead905)

Do not forget to adjust max recursion depth.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe is a good solution for this problem of yours:

```
SELECT SUM(New_Status) "Number of active users"
       , DATE_FORMAT(DATEC, '%Y-%m-%d') "Date"
FROM TEST T1
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATEC,'%H:%i:%s') = 
      (SELECT  MAX(DATE_FORMAT(T2.DATEC,'%H:%i:%s'))
       FROM TEST T2
       WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID 
       AND  DATE_FORMAT(T1.DATEC, '%Y-%m-%d') =  DATE_FORMAT(T2.DATEC, '%Y-%m-%d')
       GROUP BY  ID
                 , DATE_FORMAT(DATEC, '%Y-%m-%d'))
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATEC, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

[Here is the DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99bc62d1524e8b3ff9723f548871a853)